# Forgot password retrieve as a readable password Membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm using asp.net Membership provider. As I wanted to know about is that possible to retrieve a forgotten password as a readable password & sent it to mail? Because I saw in the membership provider password stored as an encrypted format.

If you can please provide me helpful links

Comment: You should set a new (random) password and send it via e-mail. Don't send clear-text user passwords via mail, this is VERY bad.

Comment: Are you asking, if you can send people their clear text password in case they forgot it? I surely hope not. The usual process is to generate a new (temporary) password and let them chose a new one.

Comment: @germi Yes.When someone entered his mail address ,then send the password to corresponding mail address

Comment: You really don't want to do that. Passwords should never leave your server in clear text - not via email or any way else.

Comment: @TechGuy Please don't do this (besides that it's not possible). As I said, generate a new random password (see Nayeem's answer) and send it.